# Refresh timing of Google Contacts Sync on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, contacts, gmail

I'm working on a CRM (based on web application), using Google Contacts API.

My iPhone’s contacts are linked through my **Gmail** account.

I tried to find the refresh timing between my iPhone’s contacts and the Google servers, but I can’t find it.

Does anyone know what it is? Under Settings, it says: *New data will be pushed to your iPhone from the server **when possible**.*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Gmail account is setup to use *Fetch*, which you have scheduled `Every 30 minutes`.

Your iPhone will thus sync contacts with your Gmail account every 30 minutes. You may set this to `Every 15 minutes` if you would like more responsiveness. Note that it may then take *up to* 15 minutes for your contacts to update, although it could happen much faster.

`New data will be pushed to your iPhone from the server when possible` is only an explanation for what *Push* does, and not a blanket statement for every account you have setup.

As you can see from the list underneath it, only **iCloud** is configured to use *Push* updates. **Holiday Calendar** and **Gmail** are both configured to use *Fetch*, which operates on the schedule you select at the bottom.

The reason for this is iOS simply does not support *Push* with Gmail. In fact as of iOS 10 you can only use IMAP *Push* with **iCloud** and **Yahoo** accounts. Apple has never explained this limitation, which does not exist on macOS. It is possible there was a partnership between Apple and Yahoo, since Steve Jobs made a big deal out of providing *Push* email with Yahoo during the iPhone’s original reveal.

However, as of  iOS 11 it appears that any IMAP server that supports IDLE (including **Gmail**) will finally work with *Push*.

Comment: Can you explain why is this set to fetch ?